# Error compiling iOS app with Expo SDK 49 using fastlane

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

Stack Overflow community!

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to create an iOS build after updating from Expo SDK 47 to SDK 49. When running my application in Expo Go, everything worked fine initially, and builds were successful with SDK 47. However, after updating to SDK 49, I encountered problems. It's worth noting that I'm working on Windows and testing the application in Expo Go within my development environment. When attempting to run the application, the logs from Run Fastlane display the following error messages:

```
› Packaging Pods/Pods-CiudadGPS » libPods-CiudadGPS.a

    Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'CiudadGPS' from project 'CiudadGPS')

    Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'CiudadGPS' from project 'CiudadGPS')

› Executing CiudadGPS » [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock

› Executing CiudadGPS » Start Packager on http://localhost:8081

› Executing CiudadGPS » [Expo] Configure project

› Copying   ios/CiudadGPS/Supporting/Expo.plist ➜ ./Expo.plist

› Compiling CiudadGPS » SplashScreen.storyboard

› Preparing CiudadGPS » Info.plist

› Compiling CiudadGPS » main.m

› Compiling CiudadGPS » CiudadGPS_vers.c

› Compiling CiudadGPS » AppDelegate.mm

⚠️  ld: duplicate method '+moduleName' in
┌─[category]: ExpoBridgeModule-79a36e4f3d16d3b231a616eaa42657e1.o ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a
└─[class]: ExpoBridgeModule-a299e4e2c930b50cacc0deba2982fdd8.o ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a

⚠️  ld: method '+UIStatusBarAnimation:' in category from /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-CoreModules/libReact-CoreModules.a(RCTStatusBarManager.o) conflicts with same method from another category

› Generating debug CiudadGPS » CiudadGPS.app.dSYM

› Executing CiudadGPS » Bundle React Native code and images

    Bundler cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute)

› Executing CiudadGPS » [CP] Copy Pods Resources

› Executing CiudadGPS » [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks

› Signing   CiudadGPS » CiudadGPS.app

› Creating  CiudadGPS » CiudadGPS.app

    Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')

▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

2023-07-27 05:35:07.474 xcodebuild[4721:13622] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

Exit status: 65


+-------------+-------------------------+

|           Build environment           |

+-------------+-------------------------+

| xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |

| gym_version | 2.213.0                 |

| sdk         | iPhoneOS16.4.sdk        |

+-------------+-------------------------+


Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project

It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how

to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/

Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make

sure your project is set up correctly.

fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the

the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.

Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there


[stderr] 
[!] Error building the application - see the log above

Error: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
```

I've tried various troubleshooting steps, such as updating dependencies and cleaning the project, but the issue persists. I suspect it might be related to conflicting methods during the build process.

***My latest Xcode logs were as follows:***

```
Codesigning /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app/Frameworks/libswift_Concurrency.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 69162DF430657D3ADBDC5B5B4FEA21469C7A6550 --verbose /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app/Frameworks/libswift_Concurrency.dylib

Strip /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app/CiudadGPS (in target 'CiudadGPS' from project 'CiudadGPS')
    cd /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip -D /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app/CiudadGPS

SetOwnerAndGroup expo:staff /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app (in target 'CiudadGPS' from project 'CiudadGPS')
    cd /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios
    /usr/sbin/chown -RH expo:staff /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app

SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app (in target 'CiudadGPS' from project 'CiudadGPS')
    cd /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios
    /bin/chmod -RH u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app

CodeSign /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app (in target 'CiudadGPS' from project 'CiudadGPS')
    cd /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios
    
    Signing Identity:     "iPhone Distribution: Hector Gabriel Damas Monasterios (4Z2QNGLAAF)"
    Provisioning Profile: "*[expo] com.ciudadgps.app AppStore 2023-07-21T17:49:00.225Z"
                          (3de8e743-3cd0-4f05-9299-40623a95ca1d)
    
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 69162DF430657D3ADBDC5B5B4FEA21469C7A6550 --entitlements /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/CiudadGPS.build/Release-iphoneos/CiudadGPS.build/CiudadGPS.app.xcent --generate-entitlement-der /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app

RegisterExecutionPolicyException /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app (in target 'CiudadGPS' from project 'CiudadGPS')
    cd /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios
    builtin-RegisterExecutionPolicyException /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app

Validate /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app (in target 'CiudadGPS' from project 'CiudadGPS')
    cd /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios
    builtin-validationUtility /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app

Touch /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app (in target 'CiudadGPS' from project 'CiudadGPS')
    cd /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios
    /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CiudadGPS-gfkojkxuthtydqbbdhorcxvlffha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CiudadGPS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/CiudadGPS.app

warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')
```

***eas.json:***

```
{
    "cli": {
      "version": ">= 1.2.0"
    },
    "build": {
      "development": {
        "channel": "development",
        "developmentClient": true,
        "distribution": "internal",
        "ios": {
          "resourceClass": "m-medium"
        }
      },
      "preview": {
        "distribution": "internal",
        "channel": "preview",
        "ios": {
          "resourceClass": "m-medium"
        }
      },
      "production": {
        "channel": "production",
        "env": {
          "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_KEY": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        "ios": {
          "resourceClass": "m-medium",
          "image": "latest"
        }
      }
    },
    "submit": {
      "production": {
        "ios": {
          "appleId": "XXXXXXXX",
          "ascAppId": "xxxxxxx",
          "appleTeamId": "xxxxx"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

***package.json:***

```
{
  "name": "ciudadgps",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "card-validator": "^3.0.0",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.5",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-application": "~5.3.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-store-review": "~6.4.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.11",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.27",
    "lodash.compact": "^3.0.1",
    "lodash.every": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.pick": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.values": "^4.3.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.3",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-maps": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-pell-rich-editor": "^1.8.8",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-shadow-2": "^7.0.7",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.2",
    "react-number-format": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/parser": "^7.18.4",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

***app.json:***

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "CiudadGPS",
    "slug": "Ciudadgps",
    "scheme": "ciudadgps",
    "version": "1.3.74",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ff2d31"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.ciudadgps.app",
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "CiudadGPS necesita el acceso a tu cámara.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "CiudadGPS necesita el acceso a tu ubicación para poder mostrate los comercios más cercanos a tu zona, y la distancia necesaria para descubrirlos.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "CiudadGPS necesita el acceso a tu ubicación para poder mostrate los comercios más cercanos a tu zona, y la distancia necesaria para descubrirlos.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "CiudadGPS necesita el acceso a tu ubicación para poder mostrate los comercios más cercanos a tu zona, y la distancia necesaria para descubrirlos.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Permite a $(PRODUCT_NAME) acceder a tus fotos.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "Permite a $(PRODUCT_NAME) guardar a tus fotos."
      },
      "buildNumber": "106"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.ciudadgps.app",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
      },
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "ciudadgps://"
            }
          ],
          "category": [
            "BROWSABLE",
            "DEFAULT"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ff373a"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE",
        "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.CAMERA",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"
      ],
      "versionCode": 106
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png",
      "bundler": "metro"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "La app accederá a tu galería de imágenes"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-updates",
        {
          "username": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
      ]    
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***babel.config.js:***

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
  };
};
```

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem with Expo SDK 49 and Run Fastlane on Windows? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I attempted to build my React Native app with Expo SDK 49 using fastlane after upgrading from SDK 47. Initially, everything worked fine in Expo Go with SDK 47, and I expected the same successful build experience with SDK 49.

1. Updated Expo to SDK 49 and reinstalled dependencies.
2. Ran `npx expo start` to test the app in Expo Go, and it worked without any issues.

What I expected:
I expected the build process to complete successfully as it did with Expo SDK 47. The app should generate a valid iOS build that I could test further or publish to the App Store.

Comment: Are the fastlane logs from the EAS service? Or you're really running Fastlane on Windows? I'd never heard of that.

Comment: yes, i'm using fastlane logs from EAS service.